# Opening multiple Videos in one VLC Instance with Java

Tags: java, vlc, processbuilder

I need to open a Video in the VLC Player with Java. At any point in time I need to open another Video which should play in the same Windows as the previous video. I don't want to open a new VLC instance everytime a video is played.

Currently I am using:

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe", videoInfos.filePath );
```

I also tried

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe", "—one-instance", videoInfos.filePath );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want this but why not try the following for an instance? This will play the 2nd video after a gap of 4secs overriding the first. Moreover, you used `—one-instance`, which should have been `--one-instance`. You must use `--one-instance` this even if it's the first video you are trying to play.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe", "--one-instance", videoInfos.filePath1);

ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe", "--one-instance", videoInfos.filePath2);

pb.start();
Thread.sleep(4000);
pb1.start();
```

Thanks

Comment: That was exactly my mistake! I only used on "-", but two are required! thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible to achieve that with ProcessBuilder running the external application. You just can't say to `vlc.exe` to load another movie and play. Every time you should re-create the instance of `vlc.exe`. Although if your video is played correctly you should not worry about closing of previous instance of `vlc.exe`. System will do it properly and new instance will replace existing one.

Comment: Sadly, the old instance is never closed by the system. I think I have to close it manually if that's possible. If the ProcessBuilder isn't good enough for this job, is there an alternative?

Comment: how do you know it's not closed?

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me: I mean I have two windows of the VLC Player with 2 different videos. But each time I open a new video I want it to be played in the same window. I know that I have two windows because I see them on my monitor :D